# Rendering on MetalView freezes iPhone 8

Tags: ios, iphone, freeze, metal, metalkit

When I render an image on MetalView iPhone 8 freezes.

If I choose 12Mpx image iPhone 8 freezes after some time. If I choose an 18Mpx image (or bigger), the phone freezes immediately, even hardware buttons don’t respond for some time.
On other iPhones, it reproduces very rarely.

The application continues to work, touch events come, the code is executed, but the UI is frozen.

I made a simple project without additional code, where it's easily reproducible. It also doesn't depend on UIScrollView (the project has a branch without it) and debug mode. I tested it on iPhone 8 (iOS 14.2, 4.5). On iPhones 7+, 12, 12pro it is not reproduced.

https://github.com/Sanych6666/CoreImageMetalExample

Answer (score 0):

1. Please fix code for loading image:

```
UIImage(named: "exampleImage.png")
```

to

```
UIImage(named: "exampleImage")
```

iOS much better working with just image name for this method.

2. Your's device doesn't support such big metal textures.
   So metal context can't process this.
   CIContext can, but Metal low level library so you should resolve this manually.

I recommended decrease image resoutions before send it to CIImage.

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf A11 CPU supports up to 16384 * 16384 texture. And that freeze doesn't reproduce on weaker devices (iPhone 7 Plus).

Comment: I need to render a full-resolution image. Reducing the resolution is not the right solution.

Comment: @AlexandrMaruk, yes you are right, I little bit debug code and found that:
Image too big, and this operation:
try self.context?.startTask(toRender: image, to: destination)

Finished after: 
commandBuffer.present(drawable)

Comment: I develop the photo-editing app and I have to work with large images.
`startTask` returns an asynchronous `CIRenderTask`, that will be executed. This approach works faster and with less memory usage than `context.render(_ image:...)`
I used `contextrender(_ image: CIImage, to texture: MTLTexture, commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer?, bounds: CGRect, colorSpace: CGColorSpace)` before instead of render to CIRenderDestination, it's gives the same freeze.